# Get parent URL from iframe by APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I would like to get URL in our community.
Visualforce page in community, getUrl() returns incorrect URL.

For example, On visualforce page, I can get url by this code.

```
function routerNew(){
    var url = parent.location.href;
    var splitStr = 'targetid=';
    var storeId = 'XXXXXXXX';
    var parameters = '?targetid=' + storeId;
    var link = pageUrl + parameters;    
    window.open(link, "_parent");
}
```

But, Can I do this by APEX?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a task to obtain URL for the community in the controller of vf page, that is iframed in some lightning component which is displayed on the community page, you can use a combination of [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm) and [ConnectApi.Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_Communities_static_methods.htm)

```
public PageReference getCommunityURL() {
    String ntwrkId = Network.getNetworkId();
    ConnectApi.Community comm = ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(ntwrkId);
    return new Pagereference(comm.siteUrl);
}
```

---

if you want to have URL for some community page, simply concatenate `/s/community-page-name`  to the community site url:

```
public PageReference forwardToCommunityPage(String communityPage) {
    String ntwrkId = Network.getNetworkId();
    ConnectApi.Community comm = ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(ntwrkId);
    return new Pagereference(comm.siteUrl + '/s/' + communityPage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Moreover, I want to get URL param. Can I do this?

Comment: in this case, you have to obtain these values in VF page in client js and pass them to a server-side controller via [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) or  VF remoting